# CUDA kernel gives different result even though input is the same

Tags: matrix, cuda

I want to write a CUDA kernel that will multiply 2 matrices NxN size. I did manage to do it, but without the thread cooperation... Now I want to do it with thread cooperation, and I followed the code provided in the SDK. But for some reason kernel returns different result. So here is the .cu file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include<device_functions.h>

static void HandleError(cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line)
{
    if(err!=cudaSuccess){
    printf("%s in %s file at line %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), file, line);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

#define HANDLE_ERROR(err) (HandleError(err, __FILE__, __LINE__))

#ifndef _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_
#define _MATRIXMUL_KERNEL_H_

#define ORDER 4

__global__ void matrixMul( int* A, int* B, int* C, int wA, int wB)
{
    int bx = blockIdx.x;
        int by = blockIdx.y;

    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;


    int aBegin = wA * ORDER * by;

    int aEnd   = aBegin + wA - 1;

    int aStep  = ORDER;

    int bBegin = ORDER * bx;

    int bStep  = ORDER * wB;

    int Csub=0;

    for (int a = aBegin, b = bBegin; a <= aEnd; a += aStep, b += bStep) 
    {
        __shared__ int As[ORDER][ORDER];

        __shared__ int Bs[ORDER][ORDER];

        As[ty][tx] = A[a + wA * ty + tx];
        Bs[ty][tx] = B[b + wB * ty + tx];

        __syncthreads();

        #pragma unroll

        for (int k = 0; k < ORDER; ++k)
            Csub += As[ty][k] * Bs[k][tx];

        __syncthreads();
    }

    int c = wB * ORDER * by + ORDER * bx;
    C[c + wB * ty + tx] = Csub;
}

#endif

int main()
{
    int *a=(int*)malloc(ORDER*ORDER*sizeof(int));
    int *b=(int*)malloc(ORDER*ORDER*sizeof(int));
    int *c=(int*)malloc(ORDER*ORDER*sizeof(int));

    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, ORDER*ORDER*sizeof(int*)));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, ORDER*ORDER*sizeof(int*)));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, ORDER*ORDER*sizeof(int*)));

    for(int i=0; i<ORDER*ORDER; i++)
    {
        a[i]=1;
        b[i]=2;
    }

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, ORDER*ORDER*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, ORDER*ORDER*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    matrixMul<<<ORDER, ORDER>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, ORDER, ORDER);

    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, ORDER*ORDER*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for(int i=0; i<ORDER*ORDER; i++)
    {
        if((i%ORDER)==0)
            printf("\n\n");
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<ORDER*ORDER; i++)
    {
        if((i%ORDER)==0)
            printf("\n\n");
        printf("%d\t", b[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<ORDER*ORDER; i++)
    {
        if((i%ORDER)==0)
            printf("\n\n");
        printf("%d\t", c[i]);
    }

    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);

    return 0;
}
```

Yes, I know that there is no "real" question... But if anyone could point me to wright direction I would be grateful. Thank you!

If you need more code example, let me know and I'll edit the question.

EDIT #1: I forgot to mention... I haven't been able to implement nvcc in Visual Studi 2010 so I'm unable to use debugger. Any suggestion about that?

**EDIT #2**: Updated question so it shows both CUDA kernel and main.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code. I advise you to get a copy of "Cuda by Example" there the authors do a matrix multiplication and explain everything.

Comment: I do have that book, but I couldn't find the matrix multiplication example/explanation. Though, there is an example for summing two vectors. Could it be you have mistaken those two?

Comment: I think Azrael3000 meant to refer to Programming Massively Parallel Processors by Kirk and Hwu.  That book uses a matrix multiplication kernel as an example for roughly half the book...goes into great detail.  http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Massively-Parallel-Processors-Hands-/dp/0123814723/

Comment: Z0K4 it's been a while since I read it. So yeah it's possible that there only is the summing of vectors. But then again, matrix multiplication is nothing else than summing of vectors a couple of times. So you might go from there.

Comment: True what you said about multiplying and summing... I've already wrote the kernel that multiplies matrices, but without the thread cooperation. Now I want (if it is possible) to do it with the thread cooperation so the process is faster. But thank you for your reply, and for taking time to help! ;) @Brendan Wood I just got the book, and it looks like it is just what I needed... I didn't have a chance (yet) to take a look at it, but I did go trough __Table of contents__ and there it was... Matrix multiplication example, but I still don't know if they used shared memory! Thank you!

Comment: They start with a naive implementation of matrix multiplication, and gradually improve it as they introduce more advanced concepts.  They eventually store "tiles" of the matrices in shared memory to vastly reduce the number of global memory transactions that need to take place.

Comment: There is a least one error in your host code, although it shouldn't cause the problem you are seeing. Each `cudaMalloc` call is allocating array elements of `sizeof(int*)`. That is incorrect, it should be `sizeof(int)`, but it wouldn't cause a problem because `sizeof(int*) >= sizeof(int)` on all current CUDA platforms.

Comment: Oh, that must be leftover from previous code... I'll change it when I have access to CUDA capable device and see if it works, but as you mentioned it shouldn't cause a problem I'm facing... I'll update the question as soon as possible. Thank you for the info! ;)

Comment: @talonmies I've just edited the source code and now instead of sizeof(int*) there is sizeof(int) but the result is the same. Am I doing the allocation wrong? Should I use pointer-to-pointer allocation (2D instead of 1D) for both CUDA and CPU?

Comment: :sigh: Ok, I solved the problem... Anyway, I needed 2 variables dim3 type before kernel call: `dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
dim3 dimGrid(BLOCK_SIZE/dimBlock.x, BLOCK_SIZE/dimBlock.y);` Now the kernel call looks like this: `matrixMul<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);`
Thank you all for your replies! Cheers

Comment: Please post this as an answer and accept it @Z0K4.

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel seems right, *if* your thread-geometry is `BLOCKSIZE x BLOCKSIZE`. Is that the case?

If that isn't your problem:

Since you said you got it working without thread synchronization, you probably got the memory allocation correct.

Try testing with a thread-geometry of 4x4 and the following two matrices:

```
1 1 1 1    1 0 0 0
2 2 2 2    0 1 0 0
3 3 3 3    0 0 1 0
5 5 5 5    0 0 0 1
```

The output should give you a hint as to what might be going wrong.

Comment: Sorry for my late response... I don't know how, but somehow I haven't seen your answer. Thank you for your help! I've updated my code and now the matrices are 4x4. First one is filled with 1's, and second one with 2's. The output should be matrix that consists of number 8, but every time I run program resulting matrix is always different. Any suggestion what could cause that? Did I allocate memory wrong? Again, thank you!